# Include CSS in Sharepoint2010 (non visual) Webpart

Tags: css, sharepoint, web-parts

i'm stuck for hours now to figure out how the heck i can get my Stylesheets into my Webpart. Now i've found several resources claiming on how it works

- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/manni_prince/embedding-css-file-in-custom-webpart-in-sharepoint/
- [Using custom css within a Sharepoint webpart as a Embedded Resource is not working, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471816/using-custom-css-within-a-sharepoint-webpart-as-a-embedded-resource-is-not-worki)
- some others, too, basically doing the same

Now the first one works. But it shouldn't really be needed to manually place a single CSS File in a specific folder on each System (Dev, Test, Live). There has to be a way to embedd the Webpart into the deployment file for the project.

Searching for this i came up with the second link i've posted. This pretty much LOOKS like something i wanna do, but i simply can not get it to work.

My Structure is the following:

```
./SOLUTION
  > Properties
  > References
  > ...
  > Webpart1
    > ...
  > Webpart2
    > Webpart2.css
    > ...
  > Styles (A Folder of VS Style 'Module')
    > wp2.css
```

Would someone be so kind to tell me how i can include the wp2.css into the sharepoint page only if the webpart is visible on the page. Without the need of me manually needing to place the css file as pointed out in link 1.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to set up a Web Part project so the CSS file is added to the WSP package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the `Layouts` mapped folder to the solution ([How to: Add and Remove Mapped Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231521.aspx)).
2. Create appropriate folder structure inside (e.g. `/1033/styles`) and copy the CSS file there.
3. Build the WSP package - the CSS file will be placed inside and copied to the `[14 hive]\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\styles` folder once the package is deployed.

Comment: Great, thanks! This greatly helpes me. I did the above (though i didn't create additional folder structure (/1033/styles). Then i just needed to add `CssRegistration.Register("/_layouts/MyProjectName/wp2.css");` and it all worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Creating the folder structure is an optional step - I usually do it to keep all the custom CSS files is a separate folder and therefore be able to keep track of them easily.

Comment: Okay, but isn't that already the case with Visual Studio creating a subfolder for your Project? `/Layouts/MyProjectName/file.css`. Alternatively though - i agree with that point - making one more 'grouped' folder above like `/Layouts/AllCustoms/MyProjectName/file.css` might be a good thing to do. Thanks for the advice, its appreciated a lot :)